# Matrix property question

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, matrices

Suppose $A$ is a $10$ x $10$ matrix, with the following property: given any five rows and five columns, the sum of the entries of the $5$ x $5$ matrix formed by these rows and columns is even. Prove that all the entries of $A$ are even.

Comment: This is a fun question. If you wish to show your own effort (and turn the slight trend of downvotes), you can report on what can you deduce about simpler cases. Such as: 1) if instead of 5x5 submatrices we look at 1x1 submatrices, the question becomes trivial. 2) if we look at 2x2 submatrices instead, then the claim is false. Why? Or rather, give a counterexample. 3) 3x3 submatrices???

Comment: If you work out those cases, just edit your findings into the question body. That will bump you question to the front page (and is likely to lead to some upvotes, when you have shown good faith effort).

Answer (score 2):

For a given element, choose any $5$ rows and $5$ columns in addition to those of the element. There are $5^2=25$ ways of choosing $5$ of these $6$ rows and $5$ of these $6$ columns such that the given element is included. Each of the other elements is included in an even number of these selections, only the given element is included in an odd number. Since the total sum over all these selections is even, the given element must be even.